# How to receive original request body in WSO2

Tags: wso2

Does anybody know way to receive original request payload (received via HTTP POST), in WSO2 proxies?
When i try to access $body variable - it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive HTTP POST parameters via configuring right message builder. 
By default you can find this in axis2.xml file:

```
<messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"
    contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
```

Replace that builder with this one and your parameters will appear in message body:

```
<messageBuilder class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"
    contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
```